# Using Laravel Sail with multiple docker-compose files

Tags: laravel, docker-compose

I have multiple docker-compose config files: `docker-compose.yml` `docker-compose.dev.yml`, when I'm using sail with arg `-f docker-compose.dev.yml`, I cant use any commands except docker-compose binary commands.

It's occured because inside `sail` binary commands like `artisan`, `composer` etc. executing like this:

```
elif [ "$1" == "artisan" ] || [ "$1" == "art" ];
```

So if we're using `-f docker-compose.dev.yml` arg, `artisan` command will be 3rd, not 1st so this code is running

```
# Pass unknown commands to the "docker-compose" binary...
else
    docker-compose "$@"
fi
```

How to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple to do it.

You can use sail almost like you use docker compose, so to use a different docker-compose.yml file, you could just use sail as:

```
sail -f your-custom-docker-compose.yml up -d
```